# When a lazy component is unmounted, will it unload packages used by the component?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

As I understand, lazy-loading a component will also lazy-load packages used by that component (assuming those packages aren't used elsewhere in the application). Will those packages be unloaded when the component unmounts?

For example, if a 3D viewer component uses three.js and the component is lazy-loaded, will three.js be removed from the memory when the component unmounts?